# Define a metric using scalar product and prove that it is indeed a metric

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

So this is how I went about this: $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$
such that (by definition I list the properties of scalar product) and I can east prove the first three properties of the metric defined as
$$d(x,y)= \sqrt{\langle x-y,x-y\rangle}$$
but I am having trouble with the triangle inequality, I tried adding and subtracting z in the scalar product , with hopes of somehow sorting out the inequality using the properties of scalar product , but to no luck..

Comment: `<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for that meaning only; to make angle brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: Prove the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proof) then use it to [prove the triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Applications).

Comment: I see now, thank you for the link. :)

Comment: Look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91181/proof-for-triangle-inequality-for-vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that

$$d(x,z)^2 = \langle x-z, x-z \rangle = \langle x-y+y-z, x-y+y-z \rangle$$

$$= \langle x-y, x-y \rangle + 2 \langle x-y, y-z \rangle + \langle y-z, y-z \rangle$$

$$ = d(x,y)^2 + 2 \langle x-y, y-z \rangle + d(y,z)^2$$

Then by Cauchy-Schwarz,

$$ \leq d(x,y)^2 + 2 d(x,y)d(y,z) + d(y,z)^2$$

$$ \leq \left( d(x,y) + d(y,z) \right)^2$$